# Interceptor for all PortletResponses in a JSF project

Tags: java, jsf, portlet, interceptor, jsf-1.2

I'd like to implement an interceptor that wraps around all [PortletResponses](https://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-1.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletResponse.html) in a JSF project.

But to be honest, I don't even know where to begin. I guess the `faces-config.xml` or the `web.xml` would be a good start.

We're using Java6 and JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [portlet filters](http://developers.sun.com/portalserver/reference/techart/jsr286/jsr286_2.html#Portlet_Filters).

IBM has some guides on that topic as well:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf/dx/12162009050022PMWEBTTA.htm

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0803_hepper/0803_hepper.html

Comment: I can create such a filter. But unfortunately, when I add a HTTP property to the `RenderResponse` with `setProperty`, it gets never routed to the client. The response hasn't been comitted before. The Filter is invoked, as I've seen it through logging and breakpoints.